# Mysql join with same table without reverse

Tags: mysql

im trying to reverse the join the tables to create tuples of airlines, but i don't want the reverse order to show up (ie.  and

The table is

```
+---------------+----------------------+-----------+
| flight_number | airline              | weekdays  |
+---------------+----------------------+-----------+
| AA201         | American Airlines    | Monday    |
| AA202         | American Airlines    | Wednesday |
| AA203         | American Airlines    | Friday    |
| SW1385        | South West Airline   | Thursday  |
| SW1386        | South West Airline   | Sunday    |
| SW1387        | South West Airline   | Monday    |
| TWA021        | Trans World Airlines | Tuesday   |
| TWA022        | Trans World Airlines | Wednesday |
| TWA023        | Trans World Airlines | Thursday  |
+---------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.airline, a2.airline
FROM    (SELECT airline FROM Flight) AS a1
LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT airline FROM Flight) AS a2
ON a1.airline <> a2.airline;
```

Gives the following result:

```
South West Airline  American Airlines
Trans World Airlines    American Airlines
American Airlines   South West Airline
Trans World Airlines    South West Airline
American Airlines   Trans World Airlines
South West Airline  Trans World Airlines
```

**Ideally, I want**:

```
South West Airline  American Airlines
Trans World Airlines    American Airlines
Trans World Airlines    South West Airline
```

The order does not explicitly matter either.

Comment: The order *should* matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `a1.airline < a2.airline`, intead of `a1.airline <> a2.airline` so it will only match them in one order.